# How to use nl2br and linky filter together in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, nl2br

I am trying to use multiple filters as below,

```
<p><span ng-bind-html="someVar | nl2br | linky"></span></p>
```

which renders nothing. 
However, when I change the order of filters as below

```
<p><span ng-bind-html="someVar | linky | nl2br"></span></p>
```

linky works, but nl2br fails to convert line breaks to br.

The following implementation can be used for nl2br:

```
.filter('nl2br', function($sce) {
  return function(input) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml( input.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') );
  }
}
```

Comment: Reference code for nl2br filter
http://pastebin.com/1TsdF0V6

Comment: `$sce.trustAsHtml` doesn't return a string, `linky` expects one.

Comment: I'm opening up this question for a bounty since this is a common, yet unexpectedly complex problem that teaches you about stuff you didn't want to know about in the first place. I know its important to handle user-entered HTML as untrusted, but the complexity of using $sce with simple chain of two filters just blows my mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I was able to get it work with `someVar | linky | nl2br` . The problem was with linky filter. ngSanitize's linky filter changes \r and \n to `&#10;` and `&#13;` respectively. Given nl2br filter fails to catch those.

Thanks to this gist https://gist.github.com/kensnyder/49136af39457445e5982 , modified nl2br as follows

```
angular.module('myModule')
.filter('nl2br', ['$sanitize', function($sanitize) {
    var tag = (/xhtml/i).test(document.doctype) ? '<br />' : '<br>';
    return function(msg) {
        // ngSanitize's linky filter changes \r and \n to &#10; and &#13; respectively
        msg = (msg + '').replace(/(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n|&#10;&#13;|&#13;&#10;|&#10;|&#13;)/g, tag + '$1');
        return $sanitize(msg);
    };
}]);
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fxpu89be/4/

However, it still doesn't solve the original problem of using it in reverse order i.e `someVar | nl2br | linky`

Comment: I like the way you clearly what is the problem with naive solution as well as provide simple filter that actually works. Bounty awarded. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Building on zeroflagL's comment - keep it a normal sting until the end.

```
<p><span ng-bind-html="someVar | nl2br | linky | trustMe"></span></p>
```

Removing all trust - so that we return a normal string:

```
.filter('nl2br', function($sce) {
  return function(input) {
    return input.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
  }
}
```

The last thing we want to do is add some trust:

```
.filter('trustMe', function($sce) {
  return function(input) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml( input ) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are two problems with this approach: firstly, as a minor note, you have several syntax errors. Secondly, it doesn't work; even if you run the output through `$sce.trustAsHtml` you get escaped HTML. See this fiddle for proof: http://jsfiddle.net/jsalonen/fxpu89be/2/ - if you proceed to address these problems I'm happy to give you the bounty.